# Can't build lua a project with lua in VS2010, library issue suspected

Tags: lua

I'm trying to setup a c++ console application with lua.  For whatever reason, I can't get it to build.  I think it is some issue with the .lib file.

The error I get is:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: testLua, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  testLua.cpp
1>testLua.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _luaL_newstate referenced in function _wmain
1>C:\Users\BMillek\Desktop\TestLua\testLua\Debug\testLua.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Here is what I have in main:

```
extern "C" {
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
}



lua_State* L;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    L = lua_open();

    while(true)
    ;
return 0;
}
```

I did not compile lua myself.  I got lua5_1_4_Win64_vc10_lib.zip off of SourceForge.
I am running Windows 7, 64 bit.

For Linker->Input I have 
lua5.1.lib

For VC ++ Directores->Include Directories  I have
C:\Program Files\lua5.1\include

For VC ++ Reference Directories, Library Directories I have
C:\Program Files\lua5.1

Trying to change the .lib to a invalid file name gives me a error, so I assume it is seeing it.

I figure there must be something I am missing, but I don't know what.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You must define `LUA_BUILD_AS_DLL` when using Lua as a DLL. This is done in Configuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Defines.